# Blend mode for free hand drawing overlapping UIColor

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I am using core graphics for free hand drawing on UIView. Now i want to draw with color having alpha value 0.5, When i draw first time it works fine with color. But when i redraw on same line the color becomes dark (overlapping colors). How to eliminate those already written points on the UIView and draw only once with light colors ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to clear your context.

```
clearContextBeforeDrawing to YES
```

Answer (score 0):

clear rect of current point using this....

```
            CGContextClearRect(context, CGRectMake(currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y, lineWidth, lineHeight));
```